# Importar modulos en python

Tags: python

¿Qué diferencia hay entre importar un modulo con `import nombremodulo` y `from nombremodulo import *`?

Siguiendo varios libros me he dado cuenta de que hay módulos que los importan de la primera forma, como pueda ser el modulo `os`, pero otros módulos no, como pueda ser `datetime`. He tratado de importar `datetime` de la primera forma y no me deja acceder a las funciones/métodos de dicho modulo. Para ello debo importarlo de la segunda forma.

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia de `import module` o `from module import foo` no es muy relevante, ya que en ambos casos el `module` entero es importado.

La única diferencia entre estas maneras es el **nombre** que se asocia al ambiente actual.

`import module` agrega el nombre de `module` mientras que `from module import foo` agrega `foo`.

Sobre el desempeño, tampoco existen diferentes.

En tu caso específico de `datetime` no se trata que no te permita usar `datetime` si no lo usas mediante `from datetime import datetime` sino que existen 2 cosas, el **módulo** `datetime` y la clase `datetime` dentro del módulo, que son cosas diferentes en este caso, [aquí la documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types)

Comment: Por complementar un poco la respuesta, en el [PEP8 tienes un párrafo](http://pep8.org/#imports) donde se explica muy bien para qué sirve usar un *wild import* (`from whatever import *`) y cuando conviene evitarlo. Como resumen, evítalo si no sabes lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Cuando importa `from module import foo` importa el module completo??? eso no sería con `from nombremodulo import *`

Comment: Siempre se importa el módulo completo aunque no lo tengas accesible en tu espacio de nombres. Por ejemplo, prueba lo siguiente en cualquier consola python: `from webbrowser import open_new_tab; import sys; print(sys.modules['webbrowser'].open_new)`. Ahí hemos importado 'solo' la función `open_new_tab` del módulo `webbrowser` pero, en realidad, todo el módulo está disponible, simplemente los nombres no son directamente accesibles. *Explicit better than implicit*. Esto tiene su lógica ya que, por ejemplo, `open_new_tab` puede depender de otras cosas del módulo `webbrowser` y se importa entero.